# How to stop WordPress creating multiple copies of images but keeping the size info?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if it is possible to stop WordPress from creating multiple copies of imagens, but still keeping, let's say, "medium" size.

I already edited my `functions.php` and the media options, leaving it all to "0", and it's fine. But, when I add an image do my post, the code reads as follow:

`<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image.jpg" alt="" width="2008" height="1004" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-XXXX" /></a>`

I am using Jetpack and, for design reasons, I need the code to add the size to the image and change the "size-xxxx" class. For example:

`<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/image-1280x600.jpg" alt="" width="1280"  class="aligncenter size-large wp-image-XXXX" /></a>`

I can do this all manually, yes. But is there a way that I don't need to type this things everytime? Thank you!